# How do I Do a Determine if a number in a array is a even number

Tags: delphi

I want to see if a given numbers in the array is even or not

I tried using mod 2 and to display it in a rich edit

```
   procedure TForm1.btnDisplayCriteriaClick(Sender: TObject);
   var
     Number,Check:Integer;
   begin
     redDisplay.Clear;
     if rbgCriteria.ItemIndex=2 then begin
       Number:=Numbers[ask];
       for I := 1 to ask do
         if not ODD(Number) then
            redDisplay.Lines.Add(IntToStr(Numbers[Number]));
     end;
   end;
```

Still new at delphi so I need help with my coding
I expect it to display the even numbers in the richedit but instead it gives me random integers

Comment: Delphi has a built-in function `Odd`.  If the number is an integer, if it's not odd then ...

Comment: Using `mod` operator or `Odd()` function are both correct. But your `for`-loop is not. In the loop you need to do the check for odd or not for each number from the array separately, and then write out the numbers you want as you go in the loop.

Comment: @Tom: using `x mod 2`? Really? Rather use `x and 1`. `Mod` does a (slow) division, while `and` does a fast bitwise operation.

Comment: Wow @Rudy, Instead of nitpicking to OP about the lost nanosecs due the method he had chosen, I found it more constructive to confirm the methods he used and Martyn suggested as an alternative. So, yes **really**, one can use `x mod 2` to detect even and odd numbers.

Comment: @Tom: I was nitpicking to you, not to OP. And it can very well make a big difference, in some code. Never use `mod` if you can use `and`. Rather use Odd() than mod too.

Comment: @Rudy Is that even true. Surely the Delphi compiler knows how to optimised mode 2 into an and like all real compilers do.

Comment: @David: I am not so sure, and I don't rely on the compiler to perhaps optimize code that I can reliably and very easily optimize myself. I'll check it anyway.

Comment: @rudy I guess if you are used to using a compiler that doesn't know how to perform the most basic optimisations..... But actually I think even Delphi compilers know this one. Even if it doesn't I doubt it matters in very much real world code, and it's just noise in this setting.

Comment: @David: yes, it optimizes it to `and eax,$01; test eax,eax; jnz ...`. ISTM the `test eax,eax` is unnecessary. But it is generated even with optimization on. Actually, Delphi does perform the most basic optimizations. But I don't rely on that, not in Delphi and not in any other compiler. I don't want to have to think "surely the compiler will...". especially if I can easily tell the compiler what to do, like explicitly using "x and 1 " or "Odd(x)" instead of hoping the compiler will surely optimize "x mod 2".

Comment: @David: If I use `not Odd(x)` then it generates `test bl,1; jnz ...`, which is much better than what is generated for `x mod 2 = 0` or `x and 1 = 0`.

Comment: @Rudy I didn't think I would have to state the obvious to you, but it seems I have to. I did not say that **you** were nitpicking to OP, I said **I did not**. It is fully clear that you were nitpicking to me, for not nitpicking to OP about the choise they made.

Comment: @Tom: Well "instead of nipticking to" sounded like that was what you accused me of and opposed your behaviour against it, right? So it may have been obvious to you what you meant (well duh), but not to me.

Comment: No @Rudy not right at all, but never mind, this is just useless quibble.

Comment: @Tom: with that I agree.

Comment: @RudyVelthuis I take it that you now agree that when you said "Mod does a (slow) division, while and does a fast bitwise operation" you were wrong. In fact the optimisation handles more than just `mod 2`, it is performed for all powers of 2. It's fine if you don't want to rely on that. But please don't chide us for writing clear code that the compiler optimises into bitwise operations anyway!

Comment: FWIW: @David: who is "us"? I didn't chide you, did I? Or are you the chosen advocate for all commenters?

Comment: FWIW, @David: why write "clear code" that **might** be optimized to something else if you can write equally clear code that already does that something else, i.e. doesn't have to rely on the cleverness of the compiler. Ands if you really want clear code, use the function named Odd, which clearly shows the intent. That it is faster too is nice, but not relevat to "clear code".

Comment: @RudyVelthuis I'm happy for you to write the code using `and`. That's fine if you want to do that. But if others want to use `mod` that's fine also. I'm pleased at least that you have admitted that your first comment was factually wrong.

Comment: @David: Relying on `mod` being optimized away is, IMO **not fine**. People tend to complain about relying on internal details. This is the same, but on steroids. Make sure your code is fine, and don't rely on the compiler to fix it for you.

Comment: @RudyVelthuis Now you are chiding me. Please don't.

Comment: @David: chiding you? Nah, just defending my position. ISTM you were chiding me, though, so please stop being "holier than thou".

Comment: @RudyVelthuis,@tomBrunberg. I am still new with delphi so thats why my coding is not 100% exact ... thanks for your comments guys but sorry for the poor coding

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The mistake is how you iterate the integer array. The assignment of the `Number` is done outside of the loop.

Instead, move the assignment inside the loop, as in this example:

```
procedure TForm1.btnDisplayCriteriaClick(Sender: TObject);
var
  Number : Integer;
begin
  redDisplay.Clear;
  if rbgCriteria.ItemIndex=2 then begin
    for I := 1 to ask do begin
      Number:= Numbers[I];       
      if not Odd(Number) then
        redDisplay.Lines.Add(IntToStr(Number));  // Display even number
    end;
  end;
end;
```

---

Other ways to test for an even number are:

```
if (Number mod 2) = 0 then  // Using the modulo operator
```

or

```
if (Number and 1) = 0 then // Using a bitwise test for the least significant bit
```

Comment: AFAIK, Odd() is a "magic function" and the compiler simply does something like `Result := Boolean(Param and 1);`, inline.